Why can you multiply gains from different points to get a final gain?
I don't understand this exercise (5.47 b) in specific from "fundamentals of microelectronics" 3rd edition by Behzad Razavi:

Where you have to calculate gain and I/O impedance. My issue is with the gain.
Solution of book:

It looks like the gains of two different parts were multiplied, but I don't get why.
Makes me confuse being able to multiply those two parts (my writing image) and having an Rc that is part of both calculations.
Issues I have:

Rc being part of the two calculations of gain being multiplied to get the final gain.
Having Vout/Vout2 in that place (despite being what the book is asking).

The last point I kinda understand, but I am not sure. The Ic is what is being amplified on Q2 so it would make sense to put Vout there.
The first bullet point I don't get at all. Am I not skewing the results by multiplying two gains which have a component in common?


Have you tried to find the gain expression by inspection? Also, notice the voltage divider  between RC and 1/gm2||r_pi2

I get the solution I don't understand the multiplication. I know A=A1A2... but what confuses me is the Rc. If I am multiplying let's say two stages shouldn't they be completly different from each other. It looks like Rc is interfering in both

I see. In that case, where is the problem?

It's being calculated a gain from vin to vout1 and  then being multiplied with gain from vin2 to vout2/vout. It almost looks like Rc is like a black box. When I see gains multiplying I am thinking about black boxes with an input and output and each part being multiplied to get the final gain. Multistage amplifier.I can add an image

It is treated as a black box. We know that the Rin of this box is Rc + re2. Thus, the Q1 collector voltage will be equl to Vc1/Vin = (Rc + re2)/(RE + re1) and the gain of this box is nothing more then the voltage divider --- >  Vout /Vc1 = re2/(Rc + re2). Therefore the whole stage gain Vout/Vin is Vc1/Vin * Vout/Vc1

what is the re1 of my example? My only inspection I can do at the moment is after I draw the small signal model and I realize: "Oh it looks similar to one I did, I know the answer!"

Well re1 ≈ 1/gm1

As for by inspection we can see that CE stage gain is  Rc/re  --> all the resistance seen at the collector side/ all the resistance seen at the emitter side -- RC/RE.  So if we remember this we can use it later. In your example, we have Q1 ---> CE stage. Thus RC =  (Rc + re2) and RE = (Re + re1). I also remember CC stage gain re/(re + RE) etc. But do not worry but it comes with experience.

We have a black box with Rin = Rc+re2 and seen from the end of this box to vin is Re+1/gm1 (Rout - 1st box). Giving us the Vc1/vin you calculated. The next box Rin is re2 and Rout is re2+Rc giving us the Vout/Vc1. Right? We then multiply the 2 gains

CC stage is emitter follower?

Yes, the CC stage is emitter follower.

Unfortunately, there is no good book about practical electronics, maybe The Art of Electronics gives some good inside, but this book is not for everyone. What you need is to build real-world circuits and learn from the mistakes you will for sure make as we all do.

We can treat it as a black box.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
We can treated as a black box. We know that the Rin of this box is Rc + re2. Thus, the Q1 collector voltage will be equal to:
\$ \Large \frac{V_{c1}}{V_{in}} = \frac{R_C + r_{e2}}{R_E + r_{e1}}\$
The gain of the second box is nothing more than the voltage divider gain:
\$ \Large \frac{V_{out}}{V_{c1}} = \frac{r_{e2}}{R_C + r_{e2}}\$
Therefore the whole gain is:
$$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = \frac{V_{c1}}{V_{in}} \frac{V_{out}}{V_{c1}}$$
Any additional questions?
